# Is there a way to message a user on this site?

Tags: discussion

@WilliamDeMeo closed his own question about [translating mark up into LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246121/22413) because it was a [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236439/22413).  But it seems to me that because of the way he phrased the question and titled it, it would help others searching for similar material.

So my question is how to send a notice to the OP that perhaps he should *undelete* his question?  (Obviously the way I wrote this, the OP in this case will be notified.  But it seems we shouldn't have to post to META or publicly a request to the OP.)

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Personal messaging on \`TeX.SX\`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3735)

Comment: If you're really curious and industrious and the OP has provided even just a few identifying clues you may be able to search him or her out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is quite deliberately no mechanism for direct messaging to other users. The StackExchange model is based around the idea that questions should have some general usefulness, rather than being just applicable to one person/use case. As part of that, the design of the back-end does not allow direct communication, other than public comments/chat messages. [Aside: moderators can directly contact users, but that is for serious issues only.]

On the specifics of deleting material, it is possible for other users to vote to undelete someone's question. However, most of the time it seems only reasonable that people can delete their own questions if there have been no answers.